# Is it legitimate to have Oracle JRE with OpenJdk?

Tags: java

I want to re-compile my Java Applications from Oracle Java to OpenJDK. I am using Windows 10.

I uninstalled my Oracle Java 8 and JRE 8 and set OpenJDK into class path to compile. So, I can use OpenJDK for compilation and execution. When I am trying to execute the Java program, I am getting following error

"Error: could not open `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'"

So, I updated the Windows Registry and pointed the JRE entries relevant to OpenJdk_HOME/jre location.

I am able to compile and run my program.

But is this fine way to run my program in this manner or should I only be removing JDK from machine and keep using Oracle JRE with OpenJDK, will it be legitimate to run a mix of both?

Comment: Sounds dodgy. Did you remove Oracle JRE from path, env variables etc? Can't imagine this not causing confusion and havoc on the long run.

Comment: IMHO a proper uninstall of Oracle/install of OpenJDK should have updated the registry. Weird that you had to it manually...

Comment: After making the adjustment, OpenJdk worked somehow. But When I installed the Oracle JDK 7 in Windows 10 machine, I started getting following error.          
Error: could not open `D:\Software\Java\openjdk-8u212-b03\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'